# Ainol Novo 10 Hero 2 bricked?

Tags: recovery-mode

Attempting to update my Novo 10 Hero 2 appears to have gone seriously wrong somewhere along the line, to the point the device won't boot and appears completely dead. The computer isn't recognising it when it's plugged in (as in it doesn't even recognise there's a device attached) and booting into recovery mode by holding volume up + plugging the USB cable in doesn't do the trick either. The screen doesn't light up, it doesn't make any noise - it's completely and utterly dead, or at least appears that way.

Is there anything else I can try, such as perhaps booting from the SD card, or is it completely unusable now?

Comment: Can you boot into fastboot mode? If so, that's where you start: into fastboot, flash new recovery, flash new ROM.

Comment: @TreborRude Sorry for the potentially stupid question - is that different from the normal recovery mode? If so how do I get into it?

Comment: Fastboot is indeed different than recovery. In a lot of devices, it's the mode used to flash the original operating system. I'm having a hard time finding out whether or not the Novo Hero supports it, though. Some forums seem to indicate holding Volume Down while powering on the device might work. There's a lot of good information and links available in [this article](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/48882-ainol-novo-hero-10-tipstricks-maludroids-notes/). If any of that works for you, let me know, and I'll turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: @TreborRude No luck it seems - I've tried with and without an SD card containing `u-boot.bin` and `uImage_recovery`, with the vol - / + held down with power, attached to the computer, not attached to the computer - no sign of life :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, @berry120. I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TreborRude No worries, I was really only stabbing in the dark. Thanks for the help either way.